# How do I generate Integer coordinates?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

My question is quite simple. How do I get the integer coordinates lieing strictly inside convex polygon with n vertices if all n vertices (having integer coordinates)are known.

Comment: Google *voxelization*.

Comment: Better to google `scan convert polygon`. A polygon is a 2D object, whilst voxels are 3D.

Comment: If anyone have algorithm, they can answer to this question...

Answer (score 0):

Take the floor of the lowest ordinate, let Y0 and the ceiling of the highest ordinate, let Y1.

Then consider all horizontal lines at ordinates from Y0+1 to Y1-1. By intersecting the sides, you will find exactly two intersections each time.

Take the floor of the lowest abscissa, let X0 and the ceiling of the highest abscissa, let X1.

Then enumerate the points from X0+1 to X1-1.

[image]

Comment: shall I use line sweep interesection for finding integer coordinates? Morever, check the edit for this question....

Comment: This will work for convex polygons, as specified in the question.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, can  u suggest some algorithm for finding the intersection of polygon edges and line parallel to x-axis?

Comment: @RaokfcRdkf: intersecting line segments with an horizontal line is trivial.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, won't I need the point of intersection of line parallel to x-axis and polygon edges for finding all the points lying interior to the polygon ?

Comment: @RaokfcRdkf: that's obvious.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, then can u tell me how do I get the intersection point of line parallel to x-axis and polygon edge, since what I know is only the vertices of the polygon? Please help...Sorry for my silly question but I am bit weak in geometry...

Comment: @RaokfcRdkf: lookup the equation of a line segment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, it would be great if you provide me external link for further reference...

Comment: @RaokfcRdkf What did you find on the Web ?